# ASP MVC 2: Error with dropdownlist on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, drop-down-menu

Okay i'm new to asp mvc2 and i'm experiencing some problems with the 
htmlhelper called Html.dropdownlistfor();

I want to present the user a list of days in the week. And i want the selected item to be bound to my model.

I have created this little class to generate a list of days + a short notation which i will use to store it in the database.

```
public static class days
{
    public static List<Day> getDayList()
    {
        List<Day> daylist = new List<Day>();

        daylist.Add(new Day("Monday", "MO"));
        daylist.Add(new Day("Tuesday", "TU"));
        // I left the other days out
        return daylist;
    }

    public class Dag{
        public string DayName{ get; set; }
        public string DayShortName { get; set; }

        public Dag(string name, string shortname)
        {
            this.DayName= name;
            this.DayShortName = shortname;
        }
    }
}
```

I really have now idea if this is the correct way to do it

Then i putted this in my controller:

```
SelectList _list = new SelectList(Days.getDayList(), "DayShortName", "DayName");
        ViewData["days"] = _list;
        return View("");
```

I have this line in my model

```
public string ChosenDay { get; set; }
```

And this in my view to display the list:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChosenDay, ViewData["days"] as SelectList, "--choose Day--")%>
        </div>
```

Now this all works perfect. On the first visit, But then when i'm doing a [HttpPost]
Which looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registreer(EventRegistreerViewModel model)
    {
       // I removed some unrelated code here 

       // The code below executes when modelstate.isvalid == false
        SelectList _list = new SelectList(Days.getDayList(), "DayShortName", "DayName");
        ViewData["days"] = _list;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Then i will have the following exception thrown:

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'ChosenDay' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

This errors gets thrown at the line in my view where i display the dropdown list.

I really have no idea how to solve this and tried several solutions i found online. but none of them really worked.

Ty in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen such an error.
This is becouse `ViewData["days"] as SelectList` is null when the view is rendered. This can be becouse of ViewData["days"] is null or in different type then SelectList.
The problem must be found here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registreer(EventRegistreerViewModel model)
{
}
```

Make shure, that this code

```
SelectList _list = new SelectList(Days.getDayList(), "DayShortName", "DayName");
 ViewData["days"] = _list;
```

runs and that  ViewData["days"] not null and IEnumerable before you return View. It must be becouse of Model.IsValid so ViewData["days"]  not binded.

Comment: Hey. now i notice! Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

The HttpPost controller action will call the model constructor when it sees "EventRegistreerViewModel model".

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Registreer(EventRegistreerViewModel model)
```

So if you add code to your EventRegistreerViewModel model like this:

```
...
public IEnumerable<string> MySelectList { get; set; }
public EventRegistreerViewModel() {
    // build the select the list as selectList, then
    this.MySelectList = selectList;
}
```

Then in your view use this code to display the list and the selected item:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChosenDay, model.MySelectList, "--choose Day--")
```

This way every time the view model is constructed it will include the select list